# .Net Core customise json response

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

NOTE - edited the question to make it clearer

I have the following endpoint in my code:

```
[Route("test")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<(Order order, Payment payment)>>> GetOrdersTest()
{
   // result return type is IEnumerable<(Order order, Payment payment)>
   var result = await GetTests();
   return Ok(result);
}
```

Note that the GetTests returns a list of tuples, with each tuple containing an order and payment object. And the response from this is the following:

```
[
    {
        "item1": {
            "id": 1,
            "orderAmount": 8.99
        },
        "item2": {
            "id": 2,
            "paymentAmount": 14.99
        }
    },
    {
        "item1": {
            "id": 3,
            "orderAmount": 8.99
        },
        "item2": {
            "id": 4,
            "PaymentAmount": 14.99
        }
    }
]
```

I would like the response to be like the following, such that a list is returned, with each list item containing an order and a payment. I'm trying not to create another return model just for this single case. Is there a way I can do this?

```
[
    ordersAndPayments: [{
        "order": {
            "id": 1,
            "orderAmount": 8.99
        },
        "payment": {
            "id": 2,
            "paymentAmount": 14.99
        }
    },
    {
        "order": {
            "id": 3,
            "orderAmount": 8.99
        },
        "payment": {
            "id": 4,
            "paymentAmount": 14.99
        }
    }]
]
```

UPDATE - Currently David mentioned changing the return code to:

```
return Ok(new { ordersAndPayments = result});
```

This has solved the first issue of naming the list. But it hasn't solved the problem of naming the items within the list (item1 and item2, instead of order and payment). I have temporarily created a private class which has solved it as it seems I can't serialise a tuple and define the names of the items within it.

Comment: Your intended response format is not valid JSON, so you'd need to write custom code to produce this string and return it.  (Or did you mean to make the enclosing brackets an object instead of an array, and enclose `result` in quotes?)

Comment: create a dynamic class of your own and serilize it

Comment: Your json strings are really weird. You should have some respect to check them before publishing. What do you really have orderAmount or OrderAmount, and where are from item3 and item4?

Comment: @Serve - my bad - I cant copy and paste my whole code, so I simplied it but wrote the question a little wrong. It was meant to be "item1", "item2" for both in the list (the item1 and item2 come from serialising the tuple). I have corrected the question for anyone who reads this later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code for your api

```
// result return type is IEnumerable<(Order order, Payment payment)>
   var result = await GetTests();

    var ordersAndPayments  = new
    {
        ordersAndPayments  = result.Select(t => new
        {
            order = t.Item1,
            payment = t.Item2
        })
    };

   return Ok(ordersAndPayments);
```

output

```
{
  "ordersAndPayments": [
    {
      "order": {
        "id": 1,
        "orderAmount": 8.99
      },
      "payment": {
        "id": 1,
        "paymentAmount": 14.99
      }
    },
    {
      "order": {
        "id": 2,
        "orderAmount": 10.99
      },
      "payment": {
        "id": 2,
        "paymentAmount": 15.99
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you Serge. FYI - I didn't need to do the JObject.FromObject(...) parts.

Comment: @jagdipa You are welcome! You are right, thank you for a feedback!  I am just used to typed c# so I did it automatically.  I corrected my answer. Thanks again.